# Бесконечный цикл в методе объекта в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, qt

Есть некоторый объект, перемещаем его в поток `moveToThread()`, вызываем в нем некоторый метод

```
foo()
{
    while (true)
       {}
}
```

Что будет если потом вызвать из основного потока другой метод bar() перемещенного объекта?

Comment: Угадай мелодию без нот?

Comment: Он вызовится, когда основной поток получит время на исполнение своего контексиа

Comment: вы меня не так поняли, вот я запустил в ТОМ потоке бесконечный цикл, он работает что то считает. и тут я запускаю еще один метод допустим как слот, он запустится? отработает? а тот бесконечный продолжит работу?

Comment: если ты его запустишь в том треде, то он не отработает пока бесконечный цикл не закончится

Comment: это точно? пруф?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `moveToThread` влияет только на то, в каком потоке будут вызваны слоты и обработчики событий. Например, если есть `SomeClass : public QObject`, то есть следующие варианты его поведения при помещении в отдельный поток.

```
SomeClass *a = new SomeClass;
a->moveToThread(someThread);
a->foo(); //Этот метод выполнится в текущем потоке.
QObject::connect(this, someSignal, a, &SomeClass::barSlot); //при генерации сигнала someSignal слот barSlot будет выполнен в потоке someThread
QObject::connect(this, someSignal, a, &SomeClass::barSlot, Qt::QueuedConection);//при генерации сигнала someSignal слот barSlot выполнится в потоке someThread
QObject::connect(this, someSignal, a, &SomeClass::barSlot, Qt::DirectConection);//при генерации сигнала someSignal слот barSlot выполнится в текущем потоке.
QObject::connect(this, someSignal, a, &SomeClass::barSlot, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);//при генерации сигнала someSignal слот barSlot выполнится в потоке someThread, при этом текущий поток будет приостановлен до окончания выполнения слота.
```

Те же принципы относятся к методу `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(a, "barSlot", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(arg1), Q_ARG(arg2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вызвать метод как функцию - то он выполнится в текущем потоке. Если выполнить его как слот - то он выполнится в том, если не указать это явно.

Comment: необязательно, qObject::connect() позволяет указать, в каком потоке будет вызываться слот: в вызывающем или в потоке объекта

Comment: connect() указывает ОБЪЕКТЫ сигнала и слота, а не потоки. к какому потоку будут принадлежать эти объекты дело пятое

Comment: Почему минусы? Правильный ответ же.

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, В каком потоке выполнится слот, зависит от [Qt::ConnectionType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), который задаётся как раз при соединении сигнала и слота (в методе connect).

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в потоке будет бесконечный цикл, перестанет работать эвентлуп потока (это и события и сигналы). Использование бесконечного цикла в общем и целом не приветствуется. В идеале лучше перейти к работе машины с конечными состояниями (QStateMachine). Но если уж так сильно надо, то внутри вашего цикла "пинайте" очередь сообщений.

```
foo()
{
    while (true)
       {
        // ...
        qApp->processEvents();
        // ...
        }

}
```

кроме того в концепции Qt несколько коряво будет выглядеть "вызвать из основного потока другой метод bar() перемещенного объекта". Логичнее оформить это как сигнал-слот.

Comment: вопрос отчасти был риторический, я не настоящий погромист, но мне очень интересно знать что происходит под капотом, поэтому иногда спрашиваю очевидное для знающих. Дело в том что мне нужно поллить длл драйвер последовательного адаптера, при том что у него два входа и нужно поллить каждый (OpenPort2.0)

Answer (score -2):

Если Вы передаёте ваш объект по ссылке(или указателем), то изменения в одном потоке повлияют на него и в другом, а если вы передаёте объект копированием, то в этом потоке уже будет КОПИЯ объекта, которая является другим объектом, и его изменение никак не повлияет на изначальный объект.